# Trouble with understanding the proof of the contribution of the principle part on the coefficients of the function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem

[image: The proof in the question]

- $PP(f;z_0)$ represents the principle part of $f(z)$ at pole $z_0$
- $r$ represents the order of the pole

My confusion arises in the third row where the paper gets that $$\left(1-\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^{-j}=\sum_{n≥0} {{n+j-1}\choose{n}}\left(\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^n.$$

I tried using binomial theorem to expend the left-hand side of the equality,
$$
\left(1-\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^{-j}=\sum_{n=0}^{-j}{-j\choose n}\left(\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^{n}
$$
but it does not resemble the paper's final result.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: You use the geometric progression to expand for $j=1$ and differentiate it $j-1$ times for general $j$; better to change variables $z/z_0=w$ first for ease of computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(1-\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^{-j}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-j}{n}\left(-\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+j-1}{n}\left(\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}\left(\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^n}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the paper.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

Comment: I was not previously aware of the binomial identity in step 2. Thank you a lot for pointing it out to me!

Comment: @Mihailo: You're welcome.